# How to increment SwipeView QML index multiple times on Button Click

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, swipeview

I am creating a swipeView with multiple pages/items. So in one of the page I have a button in which I want to switch from index i.e. 2 to 4. Currently When I click the button on the page, signal is sent and received to increment or decrement the index. It is working fine with one increment at a time but when I have to jump from page 2 to 4 or let say page 6 to 3, its index is not working accordingly. help required.(I am not a native English speaker so sorry for my language)
I am using following code.

This is the swipeView in which I have multiple items. some of them are shown

```
 SwipeView {
    id: view
    currentIndex: 0
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.top: parent.top

    //home
    Item {


        Loader {
            // index 0
            id: one
            source: "HomeForm.qml"
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.top: parent.top

        }
        HomeForm{
            id: home
            onIncPage: {

                view.receive(value)
            }
        }
    }
   //0 systeme
    Item{

        id: two
        Loader {
            // index 1
            id: pagetwo
            source: "SystemeForm_0.qml"
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.top: parent.top
        }

        SystemeForm_0{
            id: systemeForm
            onIncPage: {
                view.receive(value)
            }
        }

    }

Item3 {
.............
}
Item4 {

}
```

This is the javascipt function that I am using to increment or decrement the index

```
  function receive(value)
    {

        if(value > 0)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < value; i++)
            {

                view.incrementCurrentIndex()
            }
        }

        if(value < 0)
        {
                view.decrementCurrentIndex()

        }
    }
```

and finally button click event which is called when I need to switch the index

```
      HomeForm{
           Button {
                 MouseArea {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onClicked: {
                            intro2.incPage(1) // incPage is a signal ..
                            }
                 }
           }
      }
```

When I tried to go from 3 to 5. I got the following output which is not correct

```
qml: Button event  = 3
qml: before increment 3
qml: After Index Changed 4
qml: before increment 4
qml: After Index Changed 2
qml: After Index Changed 2
qml: Button event  = 2
```

intro2.incPage(1) in this call, +1 means increment one page, +2 means increment 2 pages or let say -2 means decrement 2 indices.

Comment: did you try [setCurrentIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-container.html#setCurrentIndex-method)?

Comment: yes I did try that also. Same result occured

Comment: please provide [mcve] so we can test your code.

Comment: @folibis this is git repo of the code. just clone and build to see the issue in the application window of qt creator 
https://github.com/taimoortanweer1/StackPanel-QML